# assigning text by finding control

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol

I am trying to assign text to a label by finding a control (textbox) on previous page.
The control is accurately found, but the text cannot be assigned. Intellisense does not show "Text" property. How to get the text?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Control ctContent = this.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
            Control ct = (TextBox) ctContent.FindControl("TextBox1");
            //TextBox t = (TextBox) Page.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("TextBox1");
            Label1.Text = String.Format("This is what you wrote there: {0}",ct.??????);
        }     
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean a previous page?

Comment: I have redirected to a new page. On the new page is a label to which I want to assign the text of a textbox on the initial (the one from where the control is redirected) page.

Comment: The control you are finding is on the _current_ page. If you posted it from another page, it should be in the `Forms` collection, though it is difficult to be certain without seeing the code used for posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead

```
Control ct = (TextBox) ctContent.FindControl("TextBox1");
```

just write

```
TextBox ct = (TextBox) ctContent.FindControl("TextBox1");
```